# OutlookApp not declared

Tags: vb.net, object, outlook, appointment

I found several pre-written codes to control Outlook items from vb.net. The problem now is that I keep getting an error that OutlookApp has not been declared and it might be inaccessible due to its protection level. I cannot find a possible fix to this. An obvious answer would be "Declare OutlookApp". But as what?

I feel it might have to do with library reference (in my eyes I have already imported all of the ones i need) or maybe that I first have to initiate an Outlook session through the code. My code is as follows:

```
    Friend Sub CreateAppointmentWithAttendees(meetingTitle As String, meetingDate As String,
    startTime As String, endTime As String, recipientEmail As String)

    Dim apptItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem = Nothing
    Dim recipient As Outlook.Recipient = Nothing


    If IsDate(meetingDate) And IsDate(startTime) And IsDate(endTime) Then

        apptItem =
            OutlookApp.Session.Application.CreateItem(
            Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)
        recipient = apptItem.Recipients.Add(recipientEmail)
        recipient.Type = CType(Outlook.OlMeetingRecipientType.olRequired, Integer)

        With apptItem
            .MeetingStatus = Outlook.OlMeetingStatus.olMeeting
            .Subject = meetingTitle
            .Start = DateTime.Today & " " & startTime
            .End = DateTime.Today & " " & endTime

        End With

        If apptItem.Recipients.ResolveAll Then
            apptItem.Send()
        Else
            apptItem.Display()
        End If

        'Release the COM!
        'If recipient IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(recipient)
        'If apptItem IsNot Nothing Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(apptItem)

    End If

End Sub
```

Can someone tell me whats missing in my code so i can FINALLY continue coding? Just a slight hint would be enough so I can further investigate! Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably just a variable holding a reference to the current Outlook process. Try replacing it with `Outlook.Application`.

Comment: Tried it, but this results in a new error: "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference"

Comment: Do you really have declared the var OutlookApp? OutlookApp needs to be of type Outlook.Application and has to be declared somewhere in your code

Answer (score 0):

Declare (= create) a variable called `OutlookApp` of type `Outlook.Application` at class-level and you should be good to go:

```
Dim OutlookApp As New Outlook.Application

Friend Sub CreateAppointmentWithAttendees(meetingTitle As String, meetingDate As String,
startTime As String, endTime As String, recipientEmail As String)
    ...your code...
End Sub
```